# how to set consistent padding / margin between lines of responsive-text that is transitioning in scale

Tags: css, fonts

I'm having a bit trouble with a font & css related issue and was hoping you all can help me solve this problem. This is a two-part question.

1) Is there any way I can set a consistent padding or margin size between the texts that are lowering in scale? I've tried everything, but the padding and margin seems to only correspond to the text-size...

2) Once the padding and margin consistency problem is solved, is there any way I can make both padding / margin and font-size responsive. For example, transitioning from laptop to iphone.

Below is the css and html code. I have also set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/enbLpose/2/) for functionality reference.

**CSS**

```
#text {font-family:"helvetica"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: 0.2em; height: auto;}
#text.s01 {font-size: 1000%;}
#text.s02 {font-size: 600%;}
#text.s03 {font-size: 300%;}
#text.s04 {font-size: 150%;}
#text.s05 {font-size: 80%;}
#text.s06 {font-size: 30%;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="text" class="s01">STACK</div>
<div id="text" class="s02">STACK</div>
<div id="text" class="s03">STACK</div>
<div id="text" class="s04">STACK</div>
<div id="text" class="s05">STACK</div>
<div id="text" class="s06">STACK</div>
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't have the same id multiple times, it's supposed to be unique. Next, to maintain the same distance, you can set a line-height, see:

```css
.text {font-family:"helvetica"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: 0.2em; height: auto; line-height: 100px; }
.text.s01 {font-size: 1000%;}
.text.s02 {font-size: 600%;}
.text.s03 {font-size: 300%;}
.text.s04 {font-size: 150%;}
.text.s05 {font-size: 80%;}
.text.s06 {font-size: 30%;}
```

```html
<div class="text s01">STACK</div>
<div class="text s02">STACK</div>
<div class="text s03">STACK</div>
<div class="text s04">STACK</div>
<div class="text s05">STACK</div>
<div class="text s06">STACK</div>
```

The second question is tough. You can only set the same line-height for all in absolute values. Relative values, even when using the CSS `~` selector (for siblings), will always be (hence the name) relative, in this case to the font's size.

Comment: For the css and html that you have modified (thanks!), the space between the text is still inconsistent. It seems like the line-height is responding to the text-size (percentage). I'm wondering if there is anyway the line-height can be consistent so that the space between the "STACK" can remain the same?